# c++ getline() error, no instance of overload function "getline" matches the argument list

Tags: c++, getline, overloading

I am getting the following error when using a getline() function:

no instance of overload function "getline" matches the argument list

In one class named "Time" I use it when reading in the following input:

```
istream & operator >> (istream & input, Time & C) /// An input stream for the hour     minutes and seconds
{
char ch;
input >> C.hour >> ch >> C.minute >> ch >> C.second;
getline(input,C.ampm,',');

return input;   /// Returning the input value
}
```

This works fine, but I also want to use it for another class called "Shares":

```
istream & operator >> (istream & input, Shares & C) /// An input stream for the day, month and year
{
char ch;
input >> C.price >> ch >> C.volume >> ch >> C.value >> ch;
getline(input,C.value,',');

return input;   /// Returning the input value
}
```

However, the getline function in the "shares" class is giving me the error.
Both classes are using the libraries:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
```

How can I overcome this?
Thanks

Comment: What types are C.apmp and C.value?

Comment: ampm is a string and value is a double

Comment: I think that might be the problem. That getline is expecting instream,string

Comment: See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline

Comment: is there another function I can use to read value up to a character then stop reading?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do. Isn't the line above getline already parsing your values?

Comment: @user2924752: yes, there is, and you are already using that above getline as KEYSER wrote. Why do you need to read twice into the variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> getline(input,C.value,',');

based on the comments, you wrote that `C.value` is double. That will not fly because as others pointed out, the expected parameter is a [string type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) in there.

You would need to read into a temporary string and then convert it to your double. The latter step is simple, but even simpler with C++11's [std::stod](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stod/).

Therefore, you would be writing something like this:

```
std::string valueString;
getline(input, valueString, ',');
C.value = std::stod(valueString);
```